# Wordpress Timeline Show post Monthly

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am fetching data through custom post type and category. I have added 12 category Jan to Dec and Jan has 1 posts Feb have 2 post

What I am struggling to do on January post the 2 circle is showing on the left I want only one January Circle rest of the January post under the circle.

Can you please how can i put check on category?

here is the site http://novartis.portlandvault.com/timeline/

Thanks

```
<div id="timeline">
    <?php
        //Define your custom post type name in the arguments

        $args = array('post_type' => 'timeline', 'order' => 'asc' );

        //Define the loop based on arguments

        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

        //Display the contents

        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'large') );
        $category = get_the_terms($id, 'timeline_categories'); 
        ?>

    <div class="timeline-item">
        <div class="timeline-icon">
            <div class="timeline-month">
                <?php echo $category[0]->name;?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-content right">
            <h2>
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </h2>
            <p>
                <?php echo the_content(); ?>
            </p>
            <div class="timeline_img">
                <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <?php endwhile;?>
</div>
<!-- Timeline ends here -->
```

Comment: Thanks Andres for your reply. What if I do a post January one on March? Is there any way to store categories and than check like if the post is same category than dont show timeline icon else if the category is new than show timeline icon? Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure using categories is the best way to do this. You are limiting yourself to one years worth of data. I would suggest actually using the post date to separate the posts, then your code could look something like this.

```
<div id="timeline">
  <?php
    //Define your custom post type name in the arguments
    $args = array('post_type' => 'timeline', 'order' => 'asc' );

    //Define the loop based on arguments
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    //Display the contents
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'large') );
    $category = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'timeline_categories'); 
    ?>
    <section id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">

      <?php
        if( $loop->current_post === 0 ) {
          $current_quarter = $category[0]->name; ?>
          <div class="quarterlyheading">
            <?php echo $current_quarter; ?>
            <div class="quarterlinebreak"><hr></div>
          </div>
        <?php } else {      
          $post_quarter = $category[0]->name;
          if($current_quarter != $post_quarter) { ?>
            <div class="quarterlyheading">
              <?php echo $post_quarter; ?>
              <div class="quarterlinebreak"><hr></div>
            </div>
          <?php }
        }
        $current_quarter = $post_quarter;
      ?>

      <div class="timeline-item">
        <?php
          if( $loop->current_post === 0 ) {
            $current_month = get_the_time('M'); ?>
            <div class="timeline-icon">
              <div class="timeline-month">
                <?php echo $current_month; ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          <?php } else {      
            $post_month = get_the_time('M');
            if($current_month != $post_month) { ?>
              <div class="timeline-icon">
                <div class="timeline-month">
                  <?php echo $post_month; ?>
                </div>
              </div>
            <?php }
          }
          $current_month = $post_month;
        ?>        
        <div class="timeline-content right">

          <h2>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
          </h2>
          <p>
            <?php echo the_content(); ?>
          </p>
          <div class="timeline_img">
            <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </section>
  <?php endwhile;?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Shall i add Quarterly Month on this template? Like first heading January - March underneath posts related to janaury to march, then April- June so on..?

Comment: I am not sure I am understanding your question. Do you mean if you post something today but want it under January? All you need to do is change the "published" date so that it thinks the post was published in January. Then it will group it under January and not add a second label. Again this method does not use categories, it uses the post date.

Comment: Hi Andres, thanks for your reply. I want something like this http://novartis.portlandvault.com/screenshot.jpg to show quarterly month on top and then show posts within this month

Comment: Hey Atiff, I added back your "timeline_categories", I would use this to set the January - March headline. So now when you would tag the posts in the groups that you want, and it uses a very similar logic to showing/hiding the section "quarterly heading". Hopefully that makes sense.